# GUI designer for Qt

Tags: qt, user-interface, python-3.x, pyside, gui-designer

I want to ask if there are any good GUI designers for Qt that work with PySide beside QtCreator because it's huge. But I think that every will work with PySide, as it don't have to generate python3 code but just .ui file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is [Qt Designer](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-manual.html), which is part of the Qt toolkit itself.

(NB: Depending on your platform, you may need to install some extra packages to use it).